# NTLM with Spring OAuth2.0 to access a resource server (REST)

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, ntlm

I am trying to access some resources (Rest Services) secured with OAuth2.0 from some Java code. We use the Client Credentials OAuth2.0 grant type. The Authorization Server and the Resource Server run inside a Microsoft IIS Server. The access to any resource within the Microsoft IIS Server is extra secured with NTLM authentication/ authorization.
We do the needed steps to obtain the OAuth2.0 token. For this we use the Spring OAuth framework. When Spring makes a request to the authorization server to get a access token (sending the client secret and client id) it cannot go pass the NTLM authorization layer of the IIS. For our request to the authorization server we receive a 401 (unauthorized) response.

Flow:

[image]

This is my class:

```
public class RestTest {

private String tokenUrl = “some.url”;

private String clientId = “some.clientId”;

private String clientSecret = “some.clientSecret”;

public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
    AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext defaultOAuth2ClientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), defaultOAuth2ClientContext);

    return template;
}

protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
    resource.setClientId(clientId);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
    return resource;
}

public User getUser() {
    ResponseEntity<User> userResponseEntity = restTemplate().getForEntity(baseUrl + "/user", User.class);
    return userResponseEntity.getBody();
}}
```

Do you have any ideas how should the code look in order to manage to get through NTLM and reach the authorization and then the resource server?